# Origdate in Square Brackets in References

Tags: biblatex-chicago

With `cmsdate=both` and `biblatex-chicago`, using `\textcite` or `\autocite` puts the `origdate` in square brackets.

However, under References and when I use `\cite`, `origdate` appears in round brackets.

Is there a way to make these consistent, specifically having `origdate` always appear in square brackets?

My bib file contains:

```
@book{Hayek41,
    author  = "Friedrich A. Hayek",
    date        = 1962,
    origdate    = 1941,
    title   = "The Pure Theory of Capital",
    publisher   = "Routledge",
    address = "London"
    }
```

And the tex file:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,
    authordate,     %author-date in-text form
    cmsdate=both]   %show original date
    {biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{sources.bib}

text\autocite{Hayek41}

\nocite{*}  %Show all references
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
```

In text, I get:

> (Hayek [1941] 1962).

Under the References, I get

> Hayek, Friedrich A. (1941) 1962. The Pure Theory of Capital. London: Routledge & Kegan Paul.

And using `\cite` I get

> Hayek (1941) 1962.

Comment: For future questions you may want to consider posting a fully compilable example document and not just code snippets. (See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864.) Such an "MWE" makes it easier for people to get started helping you and it also makes sure that we all talk about the same thing. Sometimes the context of code is relevant and if people have to guess then they might end up with something that is different from what you actually have and need.

Answer (score 1):

`biblatex-chicago` is a very complex style that implements very complex guidelines, so supposedly simple changes can take quite a bit of code. This is certainly the case here.

The only thing we had to do was to replace `\bibopenparen` with `\bibopenbracket` and `\bibcloseparen` with `\bibclosebracket` in the right places.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
    authordate,     %author-date in-text form
    cmsdate=both]   %show original date
    {biblatex-chicago}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:bothyear+oldstyle}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ (
    test {\ifentrytype{music}}%
    or
    test {\ifentrytype{review}}%
    or
    test {\ifentrytype{standard}}%
    or
    test {\ifentrytype{suppperiodical}}%
    or
    test {\ifentrytype{video}}%
    )
    and
    togl {cms@avdate}%
  }%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:av+labelyear+extrayear}}%
  {\iftoggle{cms@switchdates}%
    {\printtext[cmsyearhyper]{%
        \bibopenbracket
        \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
        \bibclosebracket
        \clearfield{extradate}\clearfield{extratitleyear}%
        \addspace%
        \printorigdateextra}}% \usebibmacro{origyear+endyear}
    {\iffieldundef{origyear}% ???
      {\iftoggle{cms@ordate}%
        {}%
        {\clearfield{extradate}\clearfield{extratitleyear}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:standard+labelyear+extrayear}}%
      {\iftoggle{cms@ordate}% Added test for year field ???
        {\iffieldundef{year}%
          {\usebibmacro{cite:origfirst+labelyear+extrayear}}%
          {\printtext[cmsyearhyper]{%
              \bibopenbracket
              \usebibmacro{cite:origfirst+labelyear+extrayear}%
              \bibclosebracket
              \setunit{\addspace}%\addspace% ???
              \clearfield{extradate}\clearfield{extratitleyear}%
              \printdateextra}}}%\usebibmacro{year+endyear}
        {\iffieldundef{year}%
          {\usebibmacro{cite:origfirst+labelyear+extrayear}}%
          {\printtext[cmsyearhyper]{%
              \bibopenbracket
              \clearfield{extradate}\clearfield{extratitleyear}%
              \printorigdateextra%
              % \usebibmacro{origyear+endyear}%
              \bibclosebracket
              \addspace%
              \usebibmacro{cite:standard+labelyear+extrayear}}}}}}}}%


\renewbibmacro*{bothyear+oldstyle}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ (
    test {\ifentrytype{music}}%
    or
    test {\ifentrytype{review}}%
    or
    test {\ifentrytype{standard}}%
    or
    test {\ifentrytype{suppperiodical}}%
    or
    test {\ifentrytype{video}}%
    )
    and
    togl {cms@avdate}%
  }%
  {\usebibmacro{av+labelyear+extrayear}}% \clearfield local to \printtext
  {\iftoggle{cms@switchdates}%
    {\printtext{%
        \bibopenbracket
        \usebibmacro{labelyear+extrayear}%
        \bibclosebracket
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \clearfield{extrayear}%
        \printorigdateextra}% \usebibmacro{origyear+endyear}
      \usebibmacro{clear+datefield}{}%
      \usebibmacro{clear+datefield}{orig}}%
    {\iffieldundef{origyear}%
      {\iftoggle{cms@ordate}%
        {}%
        {\clearfield{extradate}\clearfield{extratitleyear}}%
        \usebibmacro{standard+labelyear+extrayear}}%
      {\iftoggle{cms@ordate}% ???
        {\iffieldundef{year}%
          {\usebibmacro{origfirst+labelyear+extrayear}}%
          {\printtext{%
              \bibopenbracket
              \usebibmacro{origfirst+labelyear+extrayear}%
              \bibclosebracket
              \setunit*{\addspace}%
              \clearfield{extradate}\clearfield{extratitleyear}%
              \printdateextra}}}% \usebibmacro{year+endyear}
        {\iffieldundef{year}%
          {\usebibmacro{origfirst+labelyear+extrayear}}%
          {\printtext{%
              \bibopenbracket
              \clearfield{extradate}\clearfield{extratitleyear}%
              \printorigdateextra%
              % \usebibmacro{origyear+endyear}%
              \bibclosebracket
              \setunit*{\addspace}%
              \usebibmacro{standard+labelyear+extrayear}}}}%
        \usebibmacro{clear+datefield}{orig}%
        \usebibmacro{clear+datefield}{}}}}}%

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Hayek41,
  author    = {Friedrich A. Hayek},
  date      = 1962,
  origdate  = 1941,
  title     = {The Pure Theory of Capital},
  publisher = {Routledge},
  address   = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{Hayek41}
ipsum \textcite{Hayek41}
dolor \cite{Hayek41}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Hayek [1941] 1962) ipsum Hayek ([1941] 1962) dolor Hayek [1941] 1962 Hayek, Friedrich A. [1941] 1962. The Pure Theory of Capital. London: Routledge.]

Comment: I appreciate your help. Thank you very much!